# In the development of a Firefox Add-on, how would I create a new "about:" page if it is possible?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have made a small extension for Google Chrome and I would like to port it over to Firefox. However, it appears that the first thing my extension does in Chrome (replaces the new tab page with my custom page) is not allowed in Firefox anymore. So I was wondering if I could create and "about:apod" page that would load my plugin content. If not, how can I make this plugin visible in Firefox?

Manifest (Chrome):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "NASA APOD Home Page",
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
        "https://api.nasa.gov/*"
    ],
  "version": "0.1"
}
```

Then, it makes my index.html the "newtab" page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>APOD</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
            <span id="time"></span>
            <span id="title"></span>
            <span id="desc_expand" class="lnr lnr-chevron-up"></span>
            <span id="desc"></span>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you feel [overriding *about:newtab*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides) is not permitted? Doing so is supported from Firefox 54.

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension? I suspect you will see an error about your attempt to use an external resource in your HTML. Why did you not download that CSS file and include it in your extension, just like all the other libraries you are using? If you are wanting this hosted on AMO, you will need to download that and include it with your extension.

Comment: Wait, now I am confused. chrome_url_overrides in a Firefox extension?

Comment: Yes, Google chose to use the name "Chrome", when "chrome" is the generic term for everything in a browser which is not content, thus making things confusing. The `chrome_url_overrides` are not Chrome overrides they are overrides of browser chrome URLs.

Comment: Alright, so I did some research and I found a post that said that it had been blocked by firefox due to malware. Of course I can't find this post now, but I was researching before trying to port and figured I would ask the question. I just loaded the add-on in about:debugging, and it works without any changes.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. You will still need to download that CSS file and include it in your extension in order have the extension listed on AMO, or at least that's what I expect. Mozilla has more stringent requirements for what they permit being listed than what is actually possible in extensions. One of those requirements is that everything that's used to make up the extension part of your extension must be sourced from within the extension, not external. This is part of their review policies. All extensions are reviewed by a human prior to listing for security issues, etc.

Comment: Showing APOD on the new tab page should be fine, as long as the content is within an iframe, which you should be doing anyway.